# Set Template for Shared PC "Guest" Profile?

Tags: windows-10

I set up a laptop as a shared PC using [this script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-shared-or-guest-pc?tabs=powershell), and I can't figure out how to configure the "Guest" profile in a meaningful way.  Any apps I put on the desktop or taskbar settings I change in the Guest profile aren't saved after logging out - which is expected - but I don't see any way to configure the defaults for that profile.

Is there any way to change the template for the Guest profile, such as default apps, taskbar and desktop shortcuts, or other configurable items?

Answer (score 0):

True "Guest" User was discontinued some time back.  All you can do is set up your own guest - something like guest_user.

For regular users (such as I suggested) there is not a default profile. So you need to set up each guest as you wish.

Default Profiles have not be available for many years now.

Comment: If the "Guest" user was discontinued, then why is that the main option when on a workstation set up as a Shared PC?  It's a temporary user that is remade after every signout.

Comment: Since there is no Guest user anymore you have to do your own settings for each user